# Why isn't this form working?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

Is it too long?  When I fill it out and click submit, nothing happens.

```
<form action="http://www.yeahthatrocks.com/update.php" method="post">
Game Name:  <input name="game_name" type="text" size="25" maxlength="255" /><br></br>
Release Date:  <input name="release_date" type="text" size="25" /><p></p>

<p>Console:
  <select name="game_console">
    <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
    <option value="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
  </select>

  Game Category:  
  <select name="game_category">
    <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="PSN">PSN</option>
    <option value="Arcade">Arcade</option>
    <option value="Arcade">DLC</option>
  </select>

  Game Type:  
  <select name="game_type">
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Action RPG">Action RPG</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
    <option value="Board">Board</option>
    <option value="Card">Card</option>
    <option value="Casino">Casino</option>
    <option value="Educational">Educational</option>
    <option value="Fighting">Fighting</option>
    <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
    <option value="Game Show">Game Show</option>
    <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
    <option value="Music">Music</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Pinball">Pinball</option>
    <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
    <option value="Puzzle">Puzzle</option>
    <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
    <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
    <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
    <option value="Virtual Pet">Virtual Pet</option>
  </select>



 Trophy Totals:</p> 

 Bronze:  <input name="bronze_ttl" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" />
 <br/>
Silver:  <input name="Silver Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Gold:  <input name="Gold Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Platinum:  <input name="Platinum Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Hidden:  <input name="Hidden Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Xbox Pts.:  <input name="Xbox Pts Total" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" /><br/>



</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Trophies:</p>
Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[0]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[0]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[0]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[0]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[1]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[1]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[1]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[1]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[2]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[2]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[2]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[2]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[3]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[3]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[3]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[3]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[4]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[4]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[4]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[4]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[5]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[5]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[5]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[5]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[6]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[6]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[6]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[6]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[7]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[7]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[7]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[7]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[8]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[8]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[8]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[8]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[9]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[9]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[9]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[9]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[10]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[10]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[10]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[10]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[11]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[11]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[11]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[11]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[12]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[12]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[12]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[12]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[13]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[13]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[13]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[13]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[14]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[14]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[14]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[14]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[15]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[15]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[15]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[15]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[16]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[16]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[16]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[16]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[17]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[17]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[17]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[17]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[18]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[18]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[18]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[18]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[19]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[19]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[19]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[19]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[20]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[20]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[20]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[20]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[21]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[21]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[21]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[21]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[22]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[22]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[22]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[22]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[23]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[23]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[23]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[23]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[24]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[24]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[24]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[24]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[25]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[25]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[25]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[25]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[26]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[26]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[26]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[26]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[27]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[27]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[27]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[27]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[28]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[28]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[28]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[28]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[29]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[29]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[29]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[29]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[30]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[30]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[30]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[30]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[31]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[31]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[31]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[31]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[32]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[32]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[32]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[32]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[33]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[33]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[33]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[33]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[34]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[34]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[34]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[34]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[35]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[35]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[35]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[35]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[36]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[36]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[36]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[36]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[37]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[37]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[37]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[37]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[38]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[38]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[38]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[38]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>



<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the action php.  I know I still have to escape the inserts to protect from injection.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$con = mysql_connect("*********","**********","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("***********", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO games (game_name, release_date, game_category, game_type, game_console)
VALUES
('$_POST[game_name]','$_POST[release_date]','$_POST[game_category]','$_POST[game_type]','$_POST[game_console]')";

mysql_query($sql);

$sql2="INSERT INTO trophy_totals (game_name, bronze_ttl, silver_ttl, gold_ttl, plat_ttl, hidden_ttl, total_points)
VALUES
('$_POST[game_name]','$_POST[bronze_ttl]','$_POST[silver_ttl]','$_POST[gold_ttl]','$_POST[plat_ttl]','$_POST[hidden_ttl]','$_POST[total_points]')";

mysql_query($sql2);

    foreach($_POST['tr_name'] as $tr_name) {
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$tr_name['tr_name']."', '".$tr_name['tr_desc']."', '".$tr_name['tr_color']."', '".$tr_name['tr_ach_value']."')";
        mysql_query($sql3);
    }
echo "Record added";
echo $sql;

mysql_close($con)


?>
```

Comment: In the future, please trim your code down to only the most relevant bits. Many potential answerers will be put off by the wall of HTML code and simply not bother reading through it all.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, btw :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your submit button to `type="submit"`

Comment: Don't feel stupid!  Honest mistake - you were focused on the form functionality/interface.

Comment: This is a reputable site, but since being open to everyone, i'd remove your mysql connection details!