# My single-page form isn't working

Tags: php, forms

This is probably a stupid mistake, however I'm new so be easy on me.

I have this simple single-page form that submits to itself, however when I submit it, it doesn't process for some reason:

HTML:

```
<form action='form.php' method='post'>
    <input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit Data' />
</form>
```

form.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    $data = "Edited Data";
    echo $data;
} else {
    $data = "Unedited Data";
    echo $data;
}
```

The 'if statement' will only return false, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<input type='button'` <= that needs to be a submit type.

Comment: and where is your `submit` button?

Comment: <input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit Data' /> change it to  <input type='submit' name='edit' value='Edit Data' />

Comment: and you dont need to put the `form.php` in action, empty `action=""` will post the form to itself

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you have an additional input for user input, then show it. Far as I'm concerned, this question could have easily been avoided and has already been answered in comments.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [**Why isn't this form working?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6001764/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a submit button on the form.

For example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

But what are you submitting in the form, theres no data entry fields! Your looking for something like this:

```
<form action='form.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='edit' value='Edit Data' />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I know I'm not submitting anything, I deleted that part of the code to simplify the question

Comment: oh ok, it would have been nice to know that in the question, use comments like this: //data input fields. just tells people you removed code

Answer (score 1):

Replace `type="button"` by `type="submit"`.
Add an attibut `id="edit"` to your field

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="submit"` , `type="button"` will just create a button or if you want to use a button then create a function which will submit the form. use the code below.
With button

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
<form action='form.php' id="myForm" method='post'>
    <input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit Data' onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

With submit

```
<form action='form.php' method='post'>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps you